# Google charts - change axis text color

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a black chart with Google Charts, but I can't seem to change the text color of the axis. I tried some code pieces I found on the web, like:

```
hAxis: {
  color: '#FFF'
}
```

But it just doesn't work. I've managed to change the title and legend color, but not the axis text. I'm trying to set the axis text color to white, to contrast with the backgroud:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
setTimeout(function() {
  var options = {
    title: 'Test Chart',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    legendTextStyle: { color: '#FFF' },
    titleTextStyle: { color: '#FFF' },
    hAxis: {
      color: '#FFF',
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector(".chart"));
  chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    
    [
      ["Year", "T1", "T2", "T3"],
      [0, 10, 20, 30],
      [1, 10, 20, 30],
      [2, 10, 20, 30],
      [3, 10, 20, 30],
      [4, 10, 20, 30]
    ]
  
  ), options);
  
}, 100);
```

```css
.chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Comment: My use case is a little different: in case of regular charts (uncofigured colors) the texts are grey instead of black, so their contrast is low. This means that I manually have to instruct and modify every piece to really be black?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Correct usage for hAxis is using the textStyle options, in which you want the color:

```
hAxis: {
    textStyle:{color: '#FFF'}
}
```

I would also recommend using  `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` function for rendering the chart instead of timeout, at least for me 100 milliseconds was not enough

Comment: Just what i was looking for !

Answer (score 8):

I manage to change all the chart texts with one CSS.

I think this way is more confortable than configure every chart text type (title, legend, vAxis, hAxis, others).

Maybe it will be usefull for someone.

Some code (Remember to change "#chart_div" for your chart id):

```
#chart_div text {
    fill: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about how to use this code snippet?  Is this supposed to go in the options array for the chart?  Or does it go in the JS somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
**check this option value -  
  
const options: {
        legend: {
            position: string;
        };
        colors: string[];
        bar: {
            groupWidth: string;
        };
        annotations: {
            alwaysOutside: boolean;
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: number;
                auraColor: string;
                color: string;
            };
        };
        fontSize: number;
        chartArea: {
             width: '95%',
             height: '80%',
        };
        backgroundColor: {
           fill :{}
        };
        hAxis: {
            //use style for horizontal axis 
             textStyle: { color: '#FFF' }
        };
    }
```